# Preventing Makefile target recompiling

Tags: compilation, makefile

I have the following `Makefile`. For some reason when I do `make` it always rebuilds the target `test_phantom_types.o` even when I haven't modified the files.

```
GTEST_HEADERS = ${GTEST_DIR}/include/gtest/*.h \
                ${GTEST_DIR}/include/gtest/internal/*.h

BASE_DIR =  ..

BUILD_DIR = build

USER_DIR = $(BASE_DIR)/tests/src

CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -std=c++11

TESTS = test_phantom_types

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
        cd $(BUILD_DIR); \
        rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o; \
        cd ../

test_phantom_types.o : $(USER_DIR)/test_phantom_types.cpp \
                       $(BASE_DIR) $(GTEST_HEADERS)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(BASE_DIR) -c   $(USER_DIR)/test_phantom_types.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@

test_phantom_types : test_phantom_types.o
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $(addprefix     $(BUILD_DIR)/,$^) ${GTEST_DIR}/libgtest.a ${GTEST_DIR}/libgtest_main.a -o   $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $@)

check : $(TESTS)
        ./$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$^)

.PHONY : clean
```

Answer (score 2):

make is very literal.

You told it you have a target called `test_phantom_types.o` so it expects that target to generate that file.

In your case, however, it doesn't. It generates `$(BUILD_DIR)/$@` (from `-o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@`) and that's not the same thing.

So when you run `make` and make determines (from the `all` -> `test_phantom_types` -> `test_phantom_types.o` sequence) that it needs to check if it needs to build the `test_phantom_types.o` file it goes to look for it, can't find it and rebuilds it.

You can see this in the output from `make -d` if you try it.

That's why the second [Rule of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) is

> 2.Every non-.PHONY rule must update a file with the exact name of its target.
>
> Make sure every command script touches the file “$@“–not “../$@“, or “$(notdir $@)“, but exactly $@. That way you and GNU make always agree.

Comment: So what do I need to in order to make it work? Does it mean I have to 'touch' a dummy file? Seems ugly

Comment: It means you need to create the files you tell make you are going to create. Either by changing the recipe to output to where make expects it to be or by changing the target to match where you actually want to put it. (e.g. `dir/file.o` is a perfectly valid target and prerequisite just the same as `file.o`.)

Comment: But this way I can't call `make file.o` right? I would have to call `make dir/file.o` ?

Comment: Correct. But that's the file you are making so that's what you should make. If you really need an "easier" way to make that specific file by hand then you could add a `.PHONY` target that lists it as a prerequisite (e.g. `.PHONY: file` and `file: dir/file.o`).

Comment: What's the most idiomatic way to have a `Makefile` that has a separate build directory? It seems all this is quite hacky.

Comment: Pattern rules are handy for this sort of thing (and why the default makefile rule for building `.o` files from `.c` files is `%.o: %.c` because then it doesn't care what directory those are under but does put them in the same directory). If you want to split them you get to write something like `$(builddir)/%.o: $(srcdir)/%.c` which should handle arbitrary *matching* paths under the relative prefixes.